# How to make a Python threaded program (with Locks) to run on multi-process?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, queue, locking

I have a multi-threaded program, and I want to let the user choose how to run them, either in serial, multi threads or multi cores, at least at the top level. A runnable demo is shown below illustrating my program’s logic.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor
from queue import Queue
# from multiprocessing import Queue


class Handler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = Queue()  # this object is essential

    def put(self, item):
        self.queue.put(item)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            item = self.queue.get()
            # do other things on the item ...
            print(item)


class Runner:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.a = Handler()
        self.b = Handler()

    def start(self):
        self.a.put(f'{self.name}: hello a')
        self.b.put(f'{self.name}: hello b')
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
            futures = [exe.submit(r.run) for r in [self.a, self.b]]
        for future in futures:
            future.result()


# current implementation
def run_in_multi_thread():
    rA = Runner('A')
    rB = Runner('B')
    rC = Runner('C')
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
        futures = [exe.submit(r.start) for r in [rA, rB, rC]]
        for future in futures:
            future.result()


# how to implement this?
def run_in_multi_process():
    rA = Runner('A')
    rB = Runner('B')
    rC = Runner('C')
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as exe:
        futures = [exe.submit(r.start) for r in [rA, rB, rC]]
        for future in futures:
            future.result()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run_in_multi_thread()  # this is currently running fine
    run_in_multi_process()  # how to make this work as well?
```

My goal is simple, I want to put many `Runner`s into separate processes to run in true parallel.

Problem is, when I try to change the outermost `ThreadPoolExecutor` to `ProcessPoolExecutor`, python always raises `TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object`.

After googling, I know that this is because I used `queue.Queue` in all my Handlers, which uses `threading.Lock`, which is a non-pickleable class. However, I cannot avoid using them because the core functionalities are all supported by `queue.Queue` and `threading.Event` for all Handlers to communicate.

I have also tried to replace `queue.Queue` with `multiprocessing.Queue`, but this time it raises `RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance`. I also heard of third party libs, such as `dill` or `pathos`, but it causes other pickling issues, so I end up sticking to the built-in libs.

Any suggestion on how to refactor my code is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I finally came up with a working solution. I think I can also answer my own question. I have given up on using `ProcessPoolExecutor`. Right now I use `multiprocessing.Process` directly. Below is the revised demo code describing how this can work in my use case.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Process
from queue import Queue
from time import sleep


class Handler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = Queue()  # this object is essential

    def put(self, item):
        self.queue.put(item)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            item = self.queue.get()
            if item == 'exit':
                break
            # do other things on the item ...
            print(item)
            sleep(1)


class Runner:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.a = Handler()
        self.b = Handler()

    def start(self):
        # some dummy messages
        for _ in range(3):
            self.a.put(f'{self.name}: hello a')
            self.b.put(f'{self.name}: hello b')
        # request to shutdown gracefully
        self.a.put('exit')
        self.b.put('exit')
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
            futures = [exe.submit(r.run) for r in [self.a, self.b]]
            for f in futures:
                f.result()


# this requires everything to be picklable
def run_in_process_pool():
    rA = Runner('A')
    rB = Runner('B')
    rC = Runner('C')
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as exe:
        futures = [exe.submit(r.start) for r in [rA, rB, rC]]
        for future in futures:
            future.result()


# this does not pickle anything, but why?
def run_in_processes():
    rA = Runner('A')
    rB = Runner('B')
    rC = Runner('C')
    procs = [Process(target=r.start) for r in [rA, rB, rC]]
    for p in procs:
        p.start()
    for p in procs:
        p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run_in_process_pool()  # `TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object`
    run_in_processes()  # this is working
```

Surprisingly, this code won’t complain about classes not being pickleable anymore! Ends up I just use the old fashion way (i.e. create process -> start -> join). Total run time reduces from 4:39 to 1:05 (my cpu has 4 cores and true parallel run time reduces to around 1/4 makes perfect sense). The next time if you have some multi-threaded code, using `queue.Queue` or `threading.Lock` under the hood, you may consider wrapping them using `multiprocessing.Process` directly.

However I still want to know why only `ProcessPoolExecutor` requires everything to be pickleable while Process does not. To my knowledge, the Process will make a system call to create a new process, and the implementation is dependent on the os. Since I am on a Windows machine running WSL2, ,so I guess I am on Unix, and the default start method should be ‘fork’, and it just clones the whole process without the need to pickle anything?

Answer (score 2):

I had run into the same problem myself. The standard answer is:

```
def init_pool_processes(q):
    global queue
    queue = q

...

def main(tasks):
    queue = Queue()
    with Pool(initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(queue,)) as pool:
        ...
```

This will allow all the threads to share the same queue.

Note that as written, your code will never exit. Your `Handler.run` method never exits, so your futures will never have a value. You need some way of letter your runners know that there are no more jobs to run, and that there will never be any more jobs added.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. However, your suggestion may not apply for my use case, since my whole program is currently relying heavily on `queue.Queue` and `threading.Event`, and `ProcessPoolExecutor` refuses to run if anything is non-picklable. I end up using `multiprocessing.Process` to run, and surprisingly it works. I am still wondering why it can only work on Process.

BTW, my bad for missing the exit cond in the demo code, need to press Ctrl-C to exit. In the real code, the Handler will check every message from the queue and break the while loop upon an exit signal.

Answer (score 2):

Synchronization primitives indeed need to be passed by inheritance in a multiprocessing context. The `mpire` library supports this using the `shared_objects` functionality. See [docs](https://slimmer-ai.github.io/mpire/usage/workerpool/shared_objects.html).

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
from mpire import WorkerPool

class Handler: ...
class Runner: ...

def task(runners, idx):
    runners[idx].start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runners = [Runner('A'), Runner('B'), Runner('C')]
    with WorkerPool(n_jobs=3, shared_objects=runners, 
                    start_method='fork') as pool:
        pool.map(task, range(len(runners)), chunk_size=1)
```

Shared objects are passed by inheritance by mpire, which solves your problem. You do have to use `multiprocessing.Queue` if you need to communicate over multiple processes.

You can change `start_method` to `'threading'` and it will use threading instead of the default `'fork'` (on unix) or `'spawn'` on Windows.

Note that `mpire` will very soon release support for `apply`/`apply_async`, which will let you change this to:

```
runners = [Runner('A'), Runner('B'), Runner('C')]
    with WorkerPool(n_jobs=3, shared_objects=runners, 
                    start_method='fork') as pool:
        futures = [pool.apply_async(task, idx) 
                   for idx in range(len(runners))]
        for future in futures:
            future.get()
```

However, what Frank Yellin says is true. Your `run` method will never exit, so you might want to have a look at that part.